# How to create a default Magento 2 block (catalog/product_list) from a phtml file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, magento2.2.6

I'm trying to render a default block from a phtml file, without luck.
After a lot of research, I learnt that I can use this code inside a page to render the block I want:

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

How can I render the very same block, but from a PHTML file?

I've tried:

```
 $productOfCategoryBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block');
 $productOfCategoryBlock->setBlockId("catalog/product_list");
 $productOfCategoryBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 echo $productOfCategoryBlock->toHtml();
```

With no luck.

What should I put inside `setBlockId` and `setTemplate` in order to replicate that? How can I pass the category ID I want to show?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

My goal here is to render this block "catalog/product_list" by passing a category ID from the PHTML file. Something like this:

```
 $productOfCategoryBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block');
 $productOfCategoryBlock->setBlockId("catalog/product_list");
 $productOfCategoryBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $productOfCategoryBlock->setCategoryId(4);
 echo $productOfCategoryBlock->toHtml();
```

Comment: What this does? {{block type=”catalog/product_list” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}} guess get product list from category id 4

Comment: Yes, It's a block of products of one category (id 4)

Comment: then you can call the staticblock in phml

Comment: And that's exactly my question, how can I call the block from from the phtml? The code I provided does not work for me, and I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Call a static block in your phtml like below

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

then in your static block

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works for rendering a fixed category, but if I have to create a static block how can I pass the "category ID" I want to show from the PHTML?

Comment: If this works accept it as answer, for dynamic category you gotta to get data of product list by yourself only by passing category ids.

Comment: Thanks Prathap, it works but unfortunately in this way it's missing the category ID I wanted to set in the PHTML. But you are right, I was not totally clear in my first question so I'll mark this as answer. I'll edit that now. I will be grateful if you care to elaborate more on "how to pass category id to block in PTHML". I already have the category ID in my phtml file.

Comment: Has this answer useful or you need anything else?